# impossible to make fsck

Tags: linux, fsck, flash-memory

I'm trying to make a fsck to a pendrive and it says me:

```
e2fsck 1.42.8 (20-Jun-2013)
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Error reading block 40402759450689 (Invalid argument).  Ignore error? yes

Force rewrite? yes

Error writing block 40402759450689 (Invalid argument) while getting next inode from scan.  Ignore error? yes

Error storing directory block information (inode=16489, block=0, num=62814697): Memory allocation failed
e2fsck: aborted
```

I need to fix the pendrive.

Comment: Block 40,402,759,450,689 is a very impressive block to have, indeed (clearly, it doesn't really exist). Have you tried answering 'no' to 'force rewrite' there? Also, how much RAM do you have? The error says it ran out (but maybe it is confused by your 150 exabyte drive)

Comment: Thanks. I have 8 gb ram and the pen drive have only 8 gb space.

Comment: I'd copy the image of pendrive to a file and work on that, to avoid further damage...